# How to get binded Values from ion-input (Vue)

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework

I'm creating a mobile app with vue and ionic where I want to use form values in a method.
My code currently looks like this:

```
 <template>
    <ion-button @click="SendData()">Fertig</ion-button>

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Title:</ion-label>
        <ion-input v-bind:value="title" placeholder="erforderlich"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>SKU Number:</ion-label>
        <ion-input :value="skuNumber" placeholder="erforderlich"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
</template>

<script>
import { IonContent, IonHeader, IonTitle, IonToolbar, IonInput, IonItem, IonLabel }
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'MaterialEdit',
  props: {
    modalType: { type: String, default: 'Material bearbeiten' },
    material: [],
  },
  data() {
    return {
      // Form Values
      title: '',
      skuNumber: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
      SendData(){
          console.log(this.title)
      }
  },
  components: { IonContent, IonHeader, IonTitle, IonToolbar, IonInput, IonItem, IonLabel  }
});
</script>
```

My `console.log()` in the `SendData()` method prints an empty string.
As you can see I tried to bind the value of the `<ion-input>` with `v-bind` and with `:`. Both doesn't work.
Does anyone know why?

Comment: Why are you not using v-model? That is why it exists :)

Comment: Worked, thanks. Sorry I'm new to vue.

Comment: @AJT82 this doesn't work on ion-select. Do you have a solution for that?